# ECMAScript 2017: Where Did "13.2 Creating Function Objects" Go (from ES5)?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5, ecmascript-2017

In [ECMA-262, version 5.x](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-13) (aka. ECMAScript 5 | ES5), there used to be a section 13.2 called `Creating Function Objects`.

I have been searching through the latest version of the standard, [ECMAScript 2017](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html) (aka. ECMAScript 8 | ES8), but cannot find a similar description.

Section 14.1 in ES8 is called `Function Definitions`, which is the same as section 13 in ES5. That's as far as I get.

Did they remove that whole piece? I thought it was a very helpful description of what actually happens when a new function is defined.

Comment: [14.1.20: Runtime Semantics: InstantiateFunctionObject](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-function-definitions-runtime-semantics-instantiatefunctionobject) + [14.1.21: Runtime Semantics: Evaluation](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-function-definitions-runtime-semantics-evaluation)

Comment: @Andreas Thank you. Ugh, they have made it extremely hard to follow how default properties are created and set. I was specifically looking for the .prototype and .constructor properties, and how they come to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there are many more kinds of function object and function syntaxes, this changed a bit.

In ES5 we had

```
10 Executable Code and Execution Contexts
     …
10.4 Establishing an Execution Context
       …
10.4.3 Entering Function Code
10.5 Declaration Binding Instantiation
10.6 Arguments Object
   …
13 Function Definition
     (syntax and evaluation of declarations and expressions)
13.1 Strict Mode Restrictions
13.2 Creating Function Objects
13.2.1 [[Call]]
13.2.2 [[Construct]]
13.2.3 The [[ThrowTypeError]] Function Object
```

In ES8 we have

```
 9 Ordinary and Exotic Objects Behaviours
 9.1 Ordinary Object Internal Methods and Internal Slots
 9.2 ECMAScript Function Objects
 9.2.1 [[Call]] ( thisArgument, argumentsList )
 9.2.2 [[Construct]] ( argumentsList, newTarget )
 9.2.3 FunctionAllocate ( functionPrototype, strict, functionKind )
 9.2.4 FunctionInitialize ( F, kind, ParameterList, Body, Scope )
 9.2.5 FunctionCreate ( kind, ParameterList, Body, Scope, Strict [ , prototype ] )
 9.2.6 GeneratorFunctionCreate ( kind, ParameterList, Body, Scope, Strict )
       …  
14 ECMAScript Language: Functions and Classes
14.1 Function Definitions
        …
14.1.18 RS: EvaluateBody
14.1.19 RS: IteratorBindingInitialization
14.1.20 RS: InstantiateFunctionObject
14.1.21 RS: Evaluation
14.2 Arrow Function Definitions
        …
14.3 Method Definitions
        …
14.4 Generator Function Definitions
        …
14.5 Class Definitions
        …
14.6 Async Function Definitions
        …
14.7 Async Arrow Function Definitions
        …
     …
```